# How to copy the terminal output?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I executed commands in the terminal and there are outputs shown in the terminal. I want to select all the screen shown. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Is selecting it with the mouse and copying (`Ctrl-Shift-C`) not an option?

Comment: Ok , it's right ! make it as an answer so that I can remember it and so you can gain in scoring

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 options,

1. Either you can copy-paste the selected text using `Ctrl + Shift + C` and `Ctrl + Shift + V` in which you have freedom what things to copy OR
2. Redirect the text to a file using redirection

   > program1 >outputfile.txt 2>errorfile.txt

   here, all the stdout will go to outputfile.txt while all the stderr will go to errorfile.txt.

P.S. from the comments below,

3. Select the text to be pasted, and use mouse middle button (scroll wheel button) to paste it at desired place.

Comment: There's also the buffer. In most terminal emulators I've used, if you copy over some text, you can paste it elsewhere with a click of the scroll wheel.

Comment: @Rob: not only in terminals, anywhere. This trick is little known, even by some old time Linux users.

Comment: I could've sworn it wasn't working properly in my browser, don't have my netbook with me to check.

Answer (score 6):

### Save console output into a file:

1. **`tee`** command

**tee** command - read from standard input and write to standard output and files.

It automatically creates file and save, all the output of cmd `ps -ax` into a file named as `processes_info` in the same folder from where the cmd has run.

```
user@admin:~$ ps -ax | tee processes_info
```

2. **`script`** command

**script** command - make typescript of terminal session.

```
user@admin:~$ script my_console_output.txt
```

This creates a file named as `my_console_output.txt` and will open a subshell and records all information through this session.
After this, script get started and whatever the console output, it will get stored in the file `my_console_output.txt`; unless and until the script ends when the forked shell exits. (e.g., when the user types `exit` or when <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is typed.)

```
user@admin:~$ script -c "ps ax" processes_info.txt
```

- it starts the script;
- creates the file `processes_info.txt`;
- stores the console output into the file;
- end (close) the script.

  Other example:

  ```
   script -c 'echo "Hello, World!"' hello.txt
  ```

Answer (score 3):

First define a shortcut for marking all. (https://askubuntu.com/a/1291548/676490)

1. Go to Menu->Preferences->Shortcuts
2. From **Edit** selection choose "Select All"
3. Then to assign press Ctrl+Shift+A

[CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/): Biddut Mitra

---

- `Ctrl+Shift+A`
- `Ctrl+Shift+C`
- go whereever you want to paste it
- `Ctrl+v`

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to the solutions suggested above, you may get into a situation where the output was *already* printed and you weren't smart enough to know beforehand that you'd like to record it somehow.

In that case, you can at least save to a file the text that can be seen at the moment in your TTY using the backlog via `/dev/vcs#`. For example if you were using `/dev/tty1`, this terminal's backlog is available in `/dev/vcs1` so for example:

```
# cat /dev/vcs1 > tty1.log
```

Credits are reserved for The Arch Wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Copying_text_from_a_terminal#Accessing_Linux_terminal_backlog

Answer (score 0):

## For windows users

> I know this is off-topic to the question, but having all info under the same question helps rather than creating a dupe

### Scenario

- You didn't think through and let a command display it's output rather than save it to a file
- My speciic solution is for cmd.exe on windows, might work for poweshell as well (not tested)

### 1. Small amount of text

#### Option 1: use your mouse

1. click and drag mouse across the text you want to copy
   [image: See example screenshot here]
2. click enter (return key)

Now the text is in your clipboard

#### Option 2: use the "mark" menu

1. right click on the title bar and navigate down and select mark. See screenshot below
   [image: select mark menu item]
2. click and drag mouse across the text you want to copy
   [image: See example screenshot here]
3. click enter (return key)

Now the text is in your clipboard

### 2. Large amount of text

- Say, you have a lot of terminal output you want to copy
- This is limited to your terminal buffer size, so you should have selected a large terminal buffer in either defaults or in the properties of cmd window (see above screenshot for that menu item), else that text is just lost (not sure if windows stores cmd output somewhere).
- This is the main "trick" I wanted to note here. Cause even though I consider myself a power user, I didn't know this.

Here are the steps

1. right click the titlebar and nagivate and click select all
   [image: Click select all menu item]
2. click enter (return key)

Now **all the text** is in your clipboard